# The object copy received via structuredClone() is not equal to the original

Tags: javascript, node.js, deep-copy

I try creating a copy of an object with `structuredClone()` and then compare it to the original.

```
const util = require('util');

function A() {}
let obj = {
    key: new A()
};
let copy = structuredClone(obj);
console.log(util.isDeepStrictEqual(obj, copy));
```

I expect `true`, but received `false`.

Could you explain the reason?

Comment: [_"The structured clone algorithm" and "Things that don't work with structured clone"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `structuredClone` cannot clone classes or functions, so your A {} becomes {} in the cloned object.

Example:

```
const util = require('util');

function A(){ this.property = 8}
let obj = {
    key: new A()
};

let copy = structuredClone(obj);
console.log("Obj is:", obj)
console.log("Copy is:", copy)
```

That shows:

```
Obj is: { key: A { property: 8 } }
Copy is: { key: { property: 8 } }
```

As you can see, the copy is no more an A instance... is a Plain Javascript Object